I have a 1998 Toyota Corolla LE ECU and want to replace it with a 98 Toyota Corolla CE would that work for my LE Toyota Corolla aand reprogramming it
I have a 1998 Toyota Corolla LE 1.8l with a bad ECU
I found a TOYOTA COROLLA CE but I wanted to know if it’s going to work when I change them out with the new ECU TOYOTA COROLLA CE BOTH 98?
Or can I take parts of the new ECU to fix the old ECU?
Part&Vin# : 70 70  89661-02551
Can I program it with any OBD2 scanner?
